# .Net Image resizing memory leak

Tags: c#

I am trying to resize images in a batch job. When I use the .Net provided classes, memory is not properly released so OutOfMemoryException is thrown. I think I use using statements properly. The code is below:

```
    private static byte[] Resize(byte[] imageBytes, int width, int height)
    {
            using (var img = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageBytes)))
            {
                using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    double y = img.Height;
                    double x = img.Width;

                    double factor = 1;
                    if (width > 0)
                        factor = width / x;
                    else if (height > 0)
                        factor = height / y;

                    var imgOut = new Bitmap((int)(x * factor), (int)(y * factor));
                    var g = Graphics.FromImage(imgOut);
                    g.Clear(Color.White);
                    g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(factor * x),
                                                   (int)(factor * y)),
                                new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)x, (int)y), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                    imgOut.Save(outStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                    return outStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
      }
```

Alternative to this code is to use FreeImage library. When I use FreeImage, there is no memory issue. Code with FreeImage:

```
   private static byte[] Resize(byte[] imageBytes, int width, int height)
   {
        var img = new FIBITMAP();
        var rescaled = new FIBITMAP();
        try
        {
            using (var inStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
            {
                img = FreeImage.LoadFromStream(inStream);
                rescaled = FreeImage.Rescale(img, width, height, FREE_IMAGE_FILTER.FILTER_BICUBIC);

                using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    FreeImage.SaveToStream(rescaled, outStream, FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_JPEG);
                    return outStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!img.IsNull)
                FreeImage.Unload(img);

            img.SetNull();

            if (!rescaled.IsNull)
                FreeImage.Unload(rescaled);

            rescaled.SetNull();
        }
   }
```

What is missing in my first code?

Comment: You are not using a Using on the Bitmap....you also want to put a Using on the Graphics g too.

Comment: You did not dispose the `Graphics` object (`var g = Graphics.FromImage(imgOut);`)

Comment: or on the `g` object - a Graphics object

Comment: The `imgOut` (`Bitmap`) and `g` (`Graphics`) variables need to be cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks for 'FreeImage.Unload()' - couldn't assume that name of method works for diposing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your leak is with the following two lines:

```
var imgOut = new Bitmap((int)(x * factor), (int)(y * factor));
var g = Graphics.FromImage(imgOut);
```

Both `Bitmap` and `Graphics` implement `IDisposable` and should therefore be disposed when you are finished using them.

I would suggest wrapping them both in a `using` block:

```
using(imgOut = new Bitmap((int)(x * factor), (int)(y * factor)))
{
    using(var g = Graphics.FromImage(imgOut))
    {
        //rest of code...
    }
}
```

[Here is a list of GDI objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to keep an eye out for, make sure you clean them up properly if you use them.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici: Yeah, I noticed the comments. I wasn't aware of the need to dispose that so I am just investigating it first. I only ever seem to use it in a paint event handler, so perhaps that why I haven't noticed a problem before

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Imageus packet or https://imageus.dev/ resizing service for example :

https://img.imageus.dev/your+image+url?mode=cover&width=500&height=400

Answer (score 0):

A more correct way:

```
private static byte[] Resize(byte[] imageBytes, int width, int height)
    {
        using (var imagestream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
        {
            using (var img = Image.FromStream(imagestream))
            {
                using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    double y = img.Height;
                    double x = img.Width;

                    double factor = 1;
                    if (width > 0)
                        factor = width / x;
                    else if (height > 0)
                        factor = height / y;

                    using (var imgOut = new Bitmap((int)(x * factor), (int)(y * factor)))
                    {
                        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(imgOut))
                        {
                            g.Clear(Color.White);
                            g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(factor * x),
                                                   (int)(factor * y)),
                                new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)x, (int)y), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                        }

                        imgOut.Save(outStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    }

                    return outStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

 }
```

You also need to be **very** careful when allocating and deallocating large objects (ones >= 85000 bytes)...because they go on the LOH (Large Object Heap), and it is possible to fragment it and then run out of memory faster than you expect (there are various techniques to get around that if you run into that issue).

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx